# How do I prevent my website crashing when the remote server goes down?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Remote database (ie. not the main websites database) connection fails and crashes host website.

I have a website that uses a second (external) database connection to load certain data on some pages. If the remote database goes down it brings down the whole website.

It's a WordPress site and the external connection uses for example `$remote_db = new wpdb()`

I've tried a few things to deal with failures, such as:

```
if( ! $remote_db ) {
    return;
}
```

and

```
if( ! $remote_db ) {
    $remote_db = $wpdb;
}
```

and

```
if( ! $remote_db->check_connection(false) ){
    exit;
}
```

But the problem persists.

When the remote database goes down I don't mind if some pages don't load completely. I just don't want my whole site to go down because the remote database crashes.

Comment: How do I prevent my website crashing when the remote server goes down?

Comment: "How do I prevent my website crashing when the remote server goes down?" send a angry email to the **remote** database hoster why the database was down again or move to a provider where it does not happen that often

Comment: .. or simply import (every night for example) all external data from the remote database host to your local one and use teh local database as complete source..

Comment: It's not often that it crashes I'd just like it to not crash the whole website when it does.

Comment: "It's not often that it crashes I'd just like it to not crash the whole website when it does." Well it seams the server crashed or the server response was that bad enough times that you have noticed it otherwise you would not be here asking this question?

Comment: Well [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) has options how long it will wait how long it will try to connect (MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT), pretty sure PDO also has something like that.. But no idea how you can use it in WordPress code and or config..

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; from the main and remote servers?